# Proof of Poincaré's Lemma :

Tags: differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

To prove Poincaré's lemma, we construct
$$
\hat{S}_{p}: \Omega^{p}(U \times \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \Omega^{p-1}(U)
$$
Every $\omega \in \Omega ^{p}(U \times \mathbb{R})$ can be written in the form
$$
\omega=\sum f_{I}(x, t) d x_{I}+\sum g_{J}(x, t) d t \wedge d x_{J}
$$
where $I=\left(i_{1}, \ldots, i_{p}\right)$ and $J=\left(j_{1}, \ldots, j_{p-1}\right)$. We define
$$
\hat{S}_{p}(\omega)=\sum\left(\int_{0}^{1} g_{J}(x, t) d t\right) d x_{J}
$$
Then we have that
\begin{aligned}
d \hat{S}_{p}(\omega)+\hat{S}_{p+1} d(\omega) &=\sum_{J, i}\left(\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial g_{J}(x, t)}{\partial_{i}} d t\right) d x_{i} \wedge d x_{J} \\
&+ \color{red}{\sum_{I}\left(\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial f_{I}(x, t)}{\partial t} d t\right) d x_{I}-\sum_{J, i}\left(\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial g_{J}}{\partial x_{i}} d t\right) d x_{i} \wedge d x_{J}} \\
&=\sum\left(\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial f_{I}(x, t)}{\partial t} d t\right) d x_{I} \\
&=\sum f_{I}(x, 1) d x_{I}-\sum f_{I}(x, 0) d x_{I}
\end{aligned}

---

I didn't see where the red term comes from ? any help please !

Comment: When you take $\mathrm{d}\omega$ you have a $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f_I\,\mathrm{d}t\wedge\mathrm{d}x^I$ term and similar for the $g_J$.

Comment: Thank you ! can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Should this really have the group cohomology tag?

Comment: Have you done what @user10354138 suggested? Edit your post to include *those terms of $d\omega$ that have $dt$ in them*.

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation, we write $$\omega=\sum_I f_I(x,t)d{x_I}+\sum_J g_J(x,t)dt\wedge x_J.$$ Then the definition of the exterior derivative in terms of local coordinates yields

$$\begin{aligned} d\omega&=\sum_I\frac{\partial f_I(x,t)}{\partial t}dt \wedge dx_I +\sum_{J,i}\frac{\partial g_J(x,t)}{\partial x_i}dx_i \wedge dt \wedge dx_J \\&= \sum_I\frac{\partial f_I(x,t)}{\partial t}dt\wedge dx_I -\sum_{J,i}\frac{\partial g_J(x,t)}{\partial x_i}dt\wedge dx_i \wedge dx_J.\end{aligned}$$

Thus

$$\hat{S}_{p+1}(d\omega)= \sum_{I}\left(\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial f_{I}(x, t)}{\partial t} d t\right) d x_{I}-\sum_{J, i}\left(\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial g_{J}(x,t)}{\partial x_{i}} d t\right) d x_{i}\wedge dx_{J}.$$